# Two div boxs centered and same height (with images)

Tags: html, css

currently taking a course about HTML and CSS. As an assignment we've been told to replicate some parts from an online news paper.
[image: Goal]

The above picture is what I'm trying to reach. I imagine it being three div boxes. A parent one, and two child divs (right and left).

This is what it looks with what I've done:
[image: Text]

Obvious as it is, the two child div boxes wont align in height. I can't seem to figure this out, sadly.. So I hope one here can help me!

```css
.overskrift {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.div2 {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.div2-left {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

.div2-right {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}

.debat {
  color: DodgerBlue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.arkiv {
  color: white;
}

.arkiv span {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.div-2-1-img {
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
}

.div-2-2-img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>dette er div1 (første artikel)</p>
</div>



<div class="div2">
  <div class="div2-left">
    <img class="div-2-1-img" src="http://placehold.it/150">
    <p class="debat">DEBAT</p>
    <h2>Hvor er tilsynet?</h2>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left; margin-left: 25%">
      <p>Historien om udledning af spildevand vidner om norsk dobbeltmoral og dansk blåøjethed.</p>
    </div>
    <p>MIKALA SØRENSEN</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div2-right">
    <p class="arkiv"> <span>FRA ARKIVET</span></p>
    <img class="div-2-1-img" src="http://placehold.it/150">
    <h2>Som smurt i olie</h2>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left; margin-left: 10%">
      <p>Et dansk firma har i årtier importeret hele <br> tankskibe fulde af forurenet spildevand fra <br> den norske olieindustri. De fortynder det <br> med grundvand, renser det og leder det ud <br> i Agersø Sund. Lokale klager over <br> forurening og
        døde fisk. De føler, at ingen <br> lytter.</p>
    </div>
    <p>MAGNUS BODING HANSEN</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really hope someone is able to help me out here. I am really stuck.. Thanks in advance! And may you have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). By setting `display: flex` on the parent you can then add `align-items: flex-start` to tell the flex parent to make the child divs align to the start, or top. `align-items: flex-start` is actually the default, and not needed, but wanted to add for some additional context.

```
.div2 {
    align-items: flex-start;
    display: flex; // This is the important line
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}


.div2-left {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 30%;

}
.div2-right {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `vertical-align` property of your two divs from the default of `baseline` to `top`.

```css
.overskrift {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.div2 {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.div2-left {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 30%;
}

.div2-right {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20%;
}

.debat {
  color: DodgerBlue;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.arkiv {
  color: white;
}

.arkiv span {
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.div-2-1-img {
  height: 75%;
  width: 75%;
}

.div-2-2-img {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

.div2-left,
.div2-right {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>dette er div1 (første artikel)</p>
</div>



<div class="div2">
  <div class="div2-left">
    <img class="div-2-1-img" src="http://placehold.it/150">
    <p class="debat">DEBAT</p>
    <h2>Hvor er tilsynet?</h2>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left; margin-left: 25%">
      <p>Historien om udledning af spildevand vidner om norsk dobbeltmoral og dansk blåøjethed.</p>
    </div>
    <p>MIKALA SØRENSEN</p>
  </div>

  <div class="div2-right">
    <p class="arkiv"> <span>FRA ARKIVET</span></p>
    <img class="div-2-1-img" src="http://placehold.it/150">
    <h2>Som smurt i olie</h2>
    <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: left; margin-left: 10%">
      <p>Et dansk firma har i årtier importeret hele <br> tankskibe fulde af forurenet spildevand fra <br> den norske olieindustri. De fortynder det <br> med grundvand, renser det og leder det ud <br> i Agersø Sund. Lokale klager over <br> forurening og
        døde fisk. De føler, at ingen <br> lytter.</p>
    </div>
    <p>MAGNUS BODING HANSEN</p>
  </div>
</div>
```